# Passing returned variables between functions

Tags: python, function

I spent hours trying to figure out how to pass the value to a function that only prints what it receives.

```
fun1(50)    

def fun1(salary):
       salary_double = salary * salary
       salary_tax = salary 1.04
       return salary, salary_double, salary_tax

def fun2():
       print (salary, salary_double, salary_tax from fun1)
```

How can I pass the value of the returned variables in the fun1 to fun2?

Comment: ... you simple pass the returned values from fun1 to fun2, but you'll have to provide a signature that accepts arguments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just as `fun1` needs arguments to work, so does `fun2`. You can use `*args` to make this variadic, or specify that it should receive 3 values every time

```
def fun2(*args):
    print(*args)

def fun2(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
```

However at this point you're just duplicating a `print` call. Do this from `fun1` instead.

Comment: Yeah, better way I think, plus one :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I understood the question here:

```
def fun1(salary):
       salary_double = salary * salary
       salary_tax = salary * 1.04
       return salary, salary_double, salary_tax

def fun2():
  salary, salary_double, salary_tax = fun1(50)
  print (salary, salary_double, salary_tax)
```

but you can do directly:

```
 def fun3():
  for x in fun1(50):
    print(x)
```

or

```
def fun3():
  print(fun1(50))
```

or @Adam's ways:

```
def fun4():
  print(*fun1(50))
```

Comment: note that the output from your second code snippet differs from the others.

Comment: @AdamSmith yes... it puts /n between.. you are right, I like more your way

Comment: In truth, "my way" is intended to show that this method is pointless. You could just as easily do (in python3, at least...) `fun2 = print`.

Comment: @AdamSmith suuuure! but... maybe the OP do something before or after... I hope!